# How to get background for cell in tkcalendar?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkcalendar

I have this calendar and I want to get the background color for selected cell how I can do that?

```
Current_Date = str(datetime.today())
Current_Date=Current_Date[0:10].split('-')
cal = Calendar(root, selectmode="day", year=int(Current_Date[0]), 
               month=int(Current_Date[1]), day=int(Current_Date[2]))
cal.pack(pady=20)
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://tkcalendar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Calendar.html#virtual-events), a virtual `<<CalendarSelected>>` event is generated each time the user selects a day with the mouse. This means you could write an event-handler function to change the background color of the selected cell and then [`bind()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111211515id_/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) this function to the event.

Comment: You can use `cal.cget("selectbackground")`.

Comment: you don't have to convert `datetime.toda()` to string but get `Current_Date.year`, `Current_Date.month`, `Current_Date.day`

Comment: why doyou need it? I checked [source code](https://github.com/j4321/tkcalendar/blob/master/tkcalendar/calendar_.py) and I don't see method to get direct access to cell - but there is hidden `cal._calendar` which keeps all cells (in rows). But if you want to change bacground then you should rather use `tags` with assigned colors.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly I don't know why you need to access cells and why you need to know cell's background. If you want to change color in cells then you should rather use tags`

BTW: you don't have to convert date to string and split it

```
current_date = datetime.datetime.today()

cal = tkcalendar.Calendar(root, selectmode="day",
                   year=current_date.year, 
                   month=current_date.month,
                   day=current_date.day)
```

---

`tkcalendar` doesn't give direct access to cells. But there is hidden `cal._calendar` which keeps all Labels used to create cells - and this way you could try to access label which you need. But Label doesn't use directly `background` but `style` and you would have to convert style to bacground color.

---

This code display styles for all cells in current month

```
import datetime
import tkinter as tk
import tkcalendar

# --- functions

def on_click():
    #print(cal._calendar)

    # display all `labels` 
    for row in cal._calendar:
        for day in row:
            number = day['text']
            style = day['style']
            background = cal.style.configure(day['style'])['background']
            print('day: {:2} | style: {:27} | background: {}'.format(number, style, background))
            
# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

current_date = datetime.datetime.today()  # PEP8: lower_case_namas

cal = tkcalendar.Calendar(root, selectmode="day",
                   year=current_date.year, 
                   month=current_date.month,
                   day=current_date.day)
cal.pack(pady=20, padx=20)
               
button = tk.Button(root, text='Show all styles', command=on_click)
button.pack(pady=(0,20), padx=20)

print(cal.style)
root.mainloop()
```

Result:

```
day: 30 | style: normal_om..!calendar.TLabel | background: gray93
day: 1  | style: normal..!calendar.TLabel    | background: white
day: 2  | style: normal..!calendar.TLabel    | background: white
day: 3  | style: normal..!calendar.TLabel    | background: white
day: 4  | style: normal..!calendar.TLabel    | background: white
day: 5  | style: we..!calendar.TLabel        | background: gray80
day: 6  | style: we..!calendar.TLabel        | background: gray80
day: 7  | style: normal..!calendar.TLabel    | background: white
day: 8  | style: normal..!calendar.TLabel    | background: white
day: 9  | style: normal..!calendar.TLabel    | background: white
day: 10 | style: normal..!calendar.TLabel    | background: white
[...]
```

---

If you want to access when you click cell then you may have to create own class and overwrite method `_on_click`

```
import datetime
import tkinter as tk
import tkcalendar

# --- functions

class MyCalendar(tkcalendar.Calendar):
    def _on_click(self, event):
        print('LABEL:', event.widget)
        print('LABEL text :', event.widget['text'])
        print('LABEL style:', event.widget['style'])
        background = cal.style.configure(event.widget['style'])['background']
        print('LABEL background:', background)
        print('---')
        
        # run original `_on_click`
        super()._on_click(event)

   
# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

current_date = datetime.datetime.today()  # PEP8: lower_case_namas

cal = MyCalendar(root, selectmode="day",
                   year=current_date.year, 
                   month=current_date.month,
                   day=current_date.day)
cal.pack(pady=20, padx=20)
cal.bind('<<CalendarSelected>>', on_select)

root.mainloop()
```

Result (when click some dates in calendar):

```
LABEL: .!mycalendar.!frame2.!label29
LABEL text : 17
LABEL style: normal..!mycalendar.TLabel
LABEL background: white
---
LABEL: .!mycalendar.!frame2.!label32
LABEL text : 20
LABEL style: we..!mycalendar.TLabel
LABEL background: gray80
---
```